# JS tooltip works in a wrong way

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

My PHP:

```
<?php 
foreach ($query as $row){
    echo '<tr>
            <td>
                <label class="checkbox">
                '.form_checkbox('delete[]', $row['link']).anchor("site/see_art/".$row['article_id'],$row['title']).'
                <div class="tooltip-inner">'
                    .$row['description'].
                '</div>
            </td>
            <td>'
            .substr($row['pub_date'], 5, 12).
```

My jQuery:

```
<script>
$(".checkbox").mouseenter(function(){
    var $tooltip = $('.tooltip-inner', this);
    clearTimeout($tooltip.data('timeoutId'));
    $tooltip.show(200);
}).mouseleave(function(){
    var $tooltip = $('.tooltip-inner', this),
    timeoutId = setTimeout(function(){
        $tooltip.hide(200);
    }, 650);
    $tooltip.data('timeoutId', timeoutId); 
});

$(".tooltip-inner").mouseenter(function(){
    clearTimeout($(this).data('timeoutId'));
}).mouseleave(function(){
    var $tooltip = $(this),
    timeoutId = setTimeout(function(){
        $tooltip.hide(200);
    }, 650);
    $tooltip.data('timeoutId', timeoutId); 
});
</script>
            '
        </label>
        </td>
    </tr>';
}?>
```

In the PHP, I have some titles that display their description when I hover over them. Everything works fine except when I load the page the. When the page loads, the tooltips are visible until I hover over the link. After I hover over the link, the tooltips hide like they should.  I know this happens because I echo the div. Some help?

Answer (score 0):

You are not hiding your tooltips when you load the page.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.tooltip-inner').hide();
});
```

If you already have a $(document).ready() then just put the hide code at the very top.

Comment: thanks. it works, now the titles appears for 2-3 seconds until the page is load completely, after this dissapear

Comment: @user3429546 Make sure the code I have you is at the top of the page(after the jquery inclusion), not the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

if you don't want them to flicker on then off use css to hide them instead of js.

so something like this in your css

```
.tooltip-inner {
display:none;
}
```